# Как сравнить значенния в триаде последовательных строк и выбрать с максимальным из них?

Tags: sql, строки, oracle

Предоположим, есть следующие значения временного ряда:

```
10-5-8-20-30-15-20-2-14-6-50-20-30-60-25-15-0-4-2-8-10-15-12-40-20
```

Это значения столбца `y`, а столбец `x` нумерует их начиная с 1.

```sql
with axis (x,y) as (
    select rownum, to_number(column_value)
    from xmlTable (
        '10,5,8,20,30,15,20,2,14,6,50,20,30,60,25,15,0,4,2,8,10,15,12,40,20')
)
select * from axis
```

Пришел к заключению, что если значения в столбце `y` сравнить триадами одна за одной, то максимальное значение в середине триады, является точкой пика.

Как в запросе определить точки пика без использования курсора и цикла?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Compare the triplet rows together and select max of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69054758) от участника [@Just an intern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16757014/just-an-intern)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69054758

Answer (score 3):

Если `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` пока недоступна, потому что версия ниже 12c, то можно найти точки пика с помощью аналитических функций без каких-либо самосоединений таблиц:

```sql
SELECT x, y
FROM (
  SELECT x, y,
    LAG(y)  OVER (ORDER BY x) AS prev_y,
    LEAD(y) OVER (ORDER BY x) AS next_y
  FROM axis)
WHERE y > prev_y AND y > next_y
```

Или:

```sql
SELECT x, y
FROM (
  SELECT x, y,
    MAX(y) OVER (ORDER BY x RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_y,
    MAX(y) OVER (ORDER BY x RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_y
  FROM axis)
WHERE y > prev_y AND y > next_y
```

Оба датут ожидаемый результ:

```
         X          Y
---------- ----------
         5         30
         7         20
         9         14
        11         50
        14         60
        18          4
        22         15
        24         40

8 rows selected.
```

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2e14ce5ca8576ffee96fb2728724f4b3)

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69061687/6571020) от участника [@MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с последовательностями хорошо подходит [Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html#GUID-136DAC89-DA17-45C6-9E37-C9892723AC79), который был специально  разработан для таких задач.

```
select *
from axis
match_recognize (
    order by x
    measures 
        p.x as x, match_number () as pеаk#, p.y as y
    pattern (p)
    define p as p.y > prev (p.y) and p.y > next (p.y)
)
```

Точкa пика в клаузе `DEFINE` определена как: предыдущее и последующее значения Y меньше, чем текущее.

Результат (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e66d643cfb17d836f97d356cb049b030)):

```
         X      PЕАK#          Y
---------- ---------- ----------
         5          1         30
         7          2         20
         9          3         14
        11          4         50
        14          5         60
        18          6          4
        22          7         15
        24          8         40
```

Answer (score 2):

Если имеется в виду, что текущее значение в столбце `y` больше, чем значения `y` в предыдущей и последующей строке, и значения `x` действительно без пропусков (как и указано вопросе), тогда просто нужен `JOIN`:

```
select z.*
from axis z 
join axis prev on prev.x = z.x - 1 
join axis next on next.x = z.x + 1
where z.y > prev.y and z.y > next.y
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054785) от участника [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)</sub>